# Git Platform Independence?

Tags: git, window

I want to setup git server on my local network server which is windows server, and want give access clone/push/pull to multiple machines which are windows/linux based, will this become issue? is git platform independent? and please can share some basic to advance tutorials? i am new to git

Comment: Hi! Questions like this [are off-topic on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); please ask over there at [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/git+windows).

Comment: As to hosting, this question is too compilcated for a condenced summary. While Git for Windows is a native Windows port, it still has quite a number of shortcomings when it comes to *serving,* in particular, its native r/o protocol (`git://`) still has unresolved bugs in GfW. Server-side SSH in Windows also was a second-class citizen last time I checked (though I heard Microsoft was pouring resources to a proper OpenSSH port).

Comment: So I'd recommend looking at two ways to solve this: 1) run a regular install of a GNU/Linux based OS in a Hyper-V VM on that server, if possible.  Maybe give that VM access to a raw partition to make it almost a first-class server. 2) Turn to non-native Git hosting turn-key solutions such as Gitblit or Bonobo Git Server.